linux: where is all the data stored after i build an application from source?
I've got a question about where all the data gets stored, after i build something from source. I know that "it depends", but maybe you can help me with this example. When i build the jellyfin media player client, it looks like this:
mkdir ~/jmp; cd ~/jmp
git clone https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv-build.git
cd mpv-build
./use-mpv-release
./update
echo -Dlibmpv=true > mpv_options
./rebuild -j`nproc`
sudo ./install
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpv.so /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpv.so.1
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpv.so /usr/local/lib/libmpv.so.2
sudo ldconfig
cd ~/jmp/
git clone https://github.com/jellyfin/jellyfin-media-player.git
cd jellyfin-media-player
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/ -G Ninja ..
ninja
sudo ninja install
rm -rf ~/jmp/

Please correct me if I'm wrong: a directory named jmp gets created, all the raw code gets cloned into it and then it gets compiled. After that... well, the jmp directory gets removed, since i don't need the raw code anymore.
Sometimes, i got a simple directory with an executable, like building ffmpeg from source. If you scroll down to Updating FFmpeg it says:
rm -rf ~/ffmpeg_build ~/bin/{ffmpeg,ffprobe,ffplay,x264,x265}


Now can just follow the guide from the beginning.

So, i am guessing all the data from ffmpeg was stored in one place.
Where does the jellyfin media player go? I am somewhat familiar with the linux filesystem, i found the executable in /usr/local/bin/, but its hard for me to understand, where the rest of the data goes, after building the jellyfin media player in case i want to remove "everything" (application-data, logs, ect.). Is there a good way to retrace, where different parts of an application went? Or do I still have the wrong idea about how linux handles applications thanks to >15 years on Windows (%APPDATA% and so on)? Is really every application-data stored in that one executable? I hope you understand, what i mean. On windows, there are special programs, that help you to completely uninstall another program, since all the files get spread out to like 50 system-directories...
Please be kind to me, i am still learning. I know several developers, non of them using linux and i would absolutely love, to help them shipping their applications to linux. Not today, not tomorrow but i am on it :)

From the snippet you copy & pasted from the github page:  DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/  ... seems like a good starting point for your hunt for the executables, libraries and potential data files.

The command mkdir ~/jmp creates the jmp/ directory in your home directory and cd sets it as the working directory. Ususally, you'd write cd ~/jmp && cd ${_} but that's fine too.
The git clone command (there's another one below for jellyfin-media-player) downloads the sources from the git repository, the following cd command enters the directory for the sources, then it launches a couple of scripts that do unknown stuff (although ./update is fairly explicit about the goal, it says nothing about the ways & means). Unless you read what is in these scripts, you can't know what they do nor how they're configured. If you want a glimpse, just less ~/jmp/mpv-build/install.sh, everything is likely in there or in something included from there.
Look closely at all the variable definitions containing PREFIX in their name, that's what you're looking for: the paths where the resulting files are copied to, depending on what they are. By default, PREFIX=/usr/local, but you can probably change it in the Makefile or CMakefile.
The following lines are giving you hints on what it did and where it put the files. These 2 lines are creating "symbolic links" (known as "symlinks"):
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpv.so /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpv.so.1
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpv.so /usr/local/lib/libmpv.so.2

Visibly, the PREFIX is the default configuration to /usr/local.
In your ./install (probably a flavour of ./configure && make && make install), PREFIX is probably left alone, with binaries going straight into /usr/local/bin, the libraries into /usr/local/lib, and so on. If your PATH and LDCONFIG are configured correctly (they were by default, they should still be if you didn't touch them), it should work out of the box.
If you want a different behaviour and different locations, you might want to alter the PREFIX (or CMAKE_PREFIX if it's a CMake thing) to something more "isolating", such as /usr/share/mpv and /usr/share/jellyfin-media-player, but do it only if you know what you're doing (jellyfin-media-player may need to be told where to find mpv...).
